# Calling two DataSnapshot functions

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use two DataSnapshot nested. The first thing you see in the code is to pull the value DbValue from the database, and then look at whether DbValue matches the data that I selected in spinner. That spinner.with getSelectedItem (), I am pulling the DbValue values from the database correctly. I checked the Log records. But that doesn't go into if. At the moment, the two data must be equal, but do not fall within if.

[image: Firebase]

```
final DatabaseReference dbProducts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("0").child("titles");
final DatabaseReference dbProductsRooms = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("0").child("titles").child("0");
dbProductsRooms.child("places")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent( 
        new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String DbValue = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    if (DbValue == String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem())) {

                        dbProducts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                productList = new ArrayList<>();

                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                                    for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Product p = productSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                                            productList.add(p);
                                        }
                                        adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                               }
                            });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: you are accessing items from Db which are stored as array during write. It may not work. Please show your db structure as well.

Comment: I added the database

Comment: Yes please share your DB screenshot OR structure.

Comment: Can you print a log for  DbValue and check you get correct value or not which you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line -

```
if (DbValue == String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()))
```

to

```
if (DbValue.equals(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()))
```